# c# regex replace everything including a word base64, with nothing and keeping rest of the string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am wanting to take a string and find  `base64,` and get rid of that and everything prior to that

example

"asdfjljlkjaldf_base64,234u0909230948098234082304802384023094"

Notice "base64,"  ... I want ONLY everything after "base64,"

Desired:  "234u0909230948098234082304802384023094"

I was looking at this code
"string test = "hello, base64, matching";

```
string regexStrTest;
regexStrTest = @"test\s\w+";       
MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(base64,, regexStrTest);
//gets the second matched value
string value = m1[1].Value;
```

but that is not quite what I want..

Comment: Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/GwnwYi/1/) ?

Comment: You have an extra comma in the code - `Regex.Matches(base64, regexStrTest)`. Also, you need to use `@"base64,(\w+)"`  regex and grab `match.Groups[1].Value`. Does your string really contain multiple expected substrings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried a regex that matches `test`, a whitespace, and 1+ word chars. The input string just did not match it.

You may use

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"base64,(\w+)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=base64%2C%28%5Cw%2B%29&i=asdfjljlkjaldf_base64%2C234u0909230948098234082304802384023094).

The pattern matches `base64,` substring and then *captures* into Group 1 one or more word chars with `(\w+)` pattern. The captured value is stored inside `match.Groups[1].Value`, just what you get with `.Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)`.

Answer (score 2):

Why *regular expressions*? `IndexOf` + `Substring` seems to be quite enough:

```
  string source = "asdfjljlkjaldf_base64,234u0909230948098234082304802384023094";

  string tag = "base64,";

  string result = source.Substring(source.IndexOf(tag) + tag.Length);
```

Comment: What if there are more than one expected matches? And `base64` case is  used inconsistently? and there are chars like `?%$^^&` after `base64`?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: these cases (many matches and incorrect chars) should be specified in the question. In the current case as it's explained "find  `base64,` and get rid of that and everything prior to that" and then "...Notice `"base64,"` ... I want ONLY everything after `"base64,"`..." it's a possible solution.

Comment: No, in the current question there is `Regex.Matches` - this extracts **multiple occurrences** of the pattern. OP expected multiple results.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: None of those constraints are in the question.

Comment: @Douglas: Look at the code. This is in the code (the `Regex.Matches` to be more precise).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: You're right, they are expecting the *second* match.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the other answers are good.  Here is a very **simple regex**

```
string yourData = "asdfjljlkjaldf_base64,234u0909230948098234082304802384023094";
var newString = Regex.Replace(yourData, "^.*base64,", "");
```